# Routing in react?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am learning react and the course I am learning from uses a previous version of react. The tutor calls `routing` inside `ReactDom.render()`. I am not able to figure out how to get it to work inside `root.render()`. i end up getting a blank page instead of App component.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { Route, Link, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>
);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <h1>{routing}</h1>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>App component</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Applies to **React Router v6**:

You need to wrap `<App />` with the `<Router />` component

Delete the `const routing: ...` and do this instead:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <Router>
    <App />
   </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Now in your app component wrap the component you want to render with a specific route in `<Routes />`:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<ANY_COMPONENT_YOU_WANT/>} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```